# Angular 2 Load Grid on Scroll/InView

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a page with 4-5 grids and many fields. So there is a considerable scroll introduced.

Using Angular2 how can I trigger loading of the grids on scroll - that is only when the grids come into view.

I came across ng2-infinite-scroll (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-infinite-scroll).

But is there any other way I can achieve the same without using the ng2-infinite-scroll npm library?